# FIrebase Database edit Error

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have one value at database `child"received"` field. I need to update that with a new value by some Integer addition program. Actually I am trying to add that value through one `AlertDialog`, In that, I want to add the currentValue present at database with my entered value. But its keep adding those values whenever the database value changing. I couldn't be able to post the code outside the database operation. How I can achieve that?

My code

```
amountEnteredString=mAmount.getText().toString();

                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userName);
                final DatabaseReference receivedRef = ref.child(month).child(customerName).child("received");

                receivedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        currentDatabaseValueString = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                        Integer currentDatabaseValue=Integer.parseInt(currentDatabaseValueString);

                        Integer amountEntered=Integer.parseInt(amountEnteredString);

                        Integer result=currentDatabaseValue+amountEntered;

                        String resultString=Integer.toString(result);

                        receivedRef.setValue(resultString);

                        dialoag.dismiss();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        Log.w("name", "load:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

                    }

                });

            }
        });

        mBuilder.setView(mView);
        dialoag= mBuilder.create();
        dialoag.show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Why not to use that data inside?

Comment: How I can take the dataSnapshot out of the code Sir?

Comment: Can you please show me the way?

Comment: Using a custom callback as explained **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)**. So you'll be able to use it outside the `onDataChange()` method.

Comment: I am getting tye database snapshot correctly. I need to perform an addition before adding back to the database. But I cant

Comment: In this case you should use transactions. See my answer from **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307610/how-to-save-users-score-in-firebase-and-retrieve-it-in-real-time-in-android-stud)**.

Comment: Its too complicated I cant understand :(