# Like and unlike system with Firebase not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make simple like and unlike system but when I press the like button it just goes up I can not unlike,the counter doesn't go down for example if I have 5 likes and I unlike the value stays at 5. I am new to Firebase Android programming and I don't know how to implement this properly I hope someone can help me.

Here is my code, I can post the whole thing if this is not the correct one.

```
private void setUpVote(final ViewHolder holder) {
        final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final String userId = holder.post.getUser_id();
        final String postId = holder.post.getPost_id();
        holder.mUpVote.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
            @Override
            public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                reference.child("up_votes").child(holder.currentUserID).child(holder.post.getPost_id()).setValue("true");
                reference.child("posts").child(holder.post.getPost_id()).child("up_votes").child(holder.currentUserID).setValue("true");
                getUpVote(holder);
                holder.mDownVote.setEnabled(false);
                setUserPoints(userId, holder);
                setPostPoints(postId, holder);
            }

            @Override
            public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void getUpVote(final ViewHolder holder) {
        String postID = holder.post.getPost_id();
        final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference newReference = reference.child("posts").child(postID).child("up_votes");
        newReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(holder.currentUserID)) {
                    holder.upVotedByCurrentUser = true;
                    setState(holder);
                } else {
                    holder.upVotedByCurrentUser = false;
                }
                long numUpVotes = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

                holder.mCountUpVote.setText(String.valueOf(numUpVotes));
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }

    private void setDownVote(final ViewHolder holder) {
        final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final String postId = holder.post.getPost_id();
        holder.mDownVote.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
            @Override
            public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                reference.child("down_votes").child(holder.currentUserID).child(holder.post.getPost_id()).setValue("true");
                reference.child("posts").child(holder.post.getPost_id()).child("down_votes").child(holder.currentUserID).setValue("true");
                getDownVote(holder);
                holder.mUpVote.setEnabled(false);
                setPostPoints(postId, holder);
            }

            @Override
            public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void getDownVote(final ViewHolder holder) {
        String postID = holder.post.getPost_id();
        final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference newReference = reference.child("posts").child(postID).child("down_votes");
        newReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(holder.currentUserID)) {
                    holder.downVotedByCurrentUser = true;
                    setState(holder);
                } else {
                    holder.downVotedByCurrentUser = false;
                }
                long numDownVotes = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

                holder.mCountDownVote.setText(String.valueOf(numDownVotes));
            }
```

I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best way in which you can manage this kind of problems. When it comes to likes and unlikes, the first problem that comes up is related to concurrent modifications in which case you should use transactions in order to have accurate data in your database.

So in this case, I recommend you to use my answer from **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307610/how-to-save-users-score-in-firebase-and-retrieve-it-in-real-time-in-android-stud)** but instead of score you should use likes. The same principle applies.

Comment: How can I implement this, I am quite new to this stuff?

Comment: You should make your own attempt given the information in that answer, and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: Don't know how to add in the class

Comment: I will try now and ask a question on how do I implement this.

Comment: I give up I can't make it work I don't know how to implement it

Comment: Never give up. Just add another question so me and other users can help you.

Comment: I copied the project from Github and I am trying to rebuild the up vote system because it doesn't work your solution is good  but I dont know where to start and where to put the code I can show you the app that I copied and you can take a look and help me

Comment: this is the project that I copied:https://github.com/buip/glance/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/prestonbui/glancesocial/adapter/NewsFeedRecyclerViewAdapter.java

Comment: Your project has over 400 lines of code and is hard for me or for other users to debug it online. Let's stick to one problem at a time. So add another question which contains a single issue.

Comment: I dont know where to start, could you give me a hand and help me with implementing your code, I am new to firebase, I want to fix the upvote system but I dont know how

Comment: When using that code in that exampleand when you encounter problems or errors, it's best to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post a new question.

Comment: ok thank you I am giving up, I am noob, so sorry for wasting your time.