# How to restrict users from writing more than once in a database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a Bus booking app. So whenever a user books a ride I will store his credentials(name, email) for that particular ride. I need to restrict the number of bookings for that ride(like only 20 per ride). To do this I am using Firebase transactions. But how to restrict them from booking more than once for a particular time in a day. Can anyone tell me how? Below is my code for database(mref1 is the location where I want to store the number of bookings)

```
private DatabaseReference mTime1;
private DatabaseReference mTime2;
private DatabaseReference mCount1;
private DatabaseReference mCount2;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private static final String TAG = "BookingActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mDatabase1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Time1");
    mDatabase2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Time2");
    mref1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Count@Time1");
    mref2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Count@Time2");

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Book(mDatabase1,mref1);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Book(mDatabase2,mref2);
        }
    });

}


public void Book(DatabaseReference mDatabase,DatabaseReference mref) {

    final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    HashMap<String,String>datamap = new HashMap<>();
    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    String ts = tsLong.toString();

    if(user!=null) {
        datamap.put("Name", user.getDisplayName());
        datamap.put("Email", user.getEmail());
        datamap.put("Timestamp",ts);
    }

    mDatabase.push().setValue(datamap);
    Update(mref);
    Toast.makeText(BookingActivity.this, "Booked Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void Update(DatabaseReference mDatabase) {

    mDatabase.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(@NonNull MutableData mutableData) {

            Integer CurrentValue = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
            mutableData.setValue(CurrentValue+1);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, @Nullable DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Updating count transaction is completed.");
        }
    });
}
```

my database structure is [image]

Comment: set a unique index to the field

Comment: Why not use the user uid instead of push() id?

Comment: can u explain @AlanDeep

Comment: @AndréKool how to use the uid?

Comment: `mDatabase.child(uid).setValue(datamap);` I think

Comment: But how did that answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you should create another node named `users` in which you should add user objects. Each user object should have a property named `numberOfRides` with the default value of `0` (zero). After the first ride, increase that numer to `1` (one) and everytime a user wants to take another ride, check the value of this property. If it is `0` let the user get the ride otherwise, restrict him from getting the ride. Then, I recommend you write a function in [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) that can set the value for the `numberOfRides` property for each user to `0` (zero). In the end just set a [cron job](https://cron-job.org/en/) to call this function by midnight. That's it!

Comment: I thought of this solution but I don't know how to write cloud functions.Is there any cloud function to do that task?

Comment: There is no predifined function that can do that, you should create your own one. But this is basically again another question, that cannot be answered in a comment. So please post again another question, regarding this request.

Comment: Are you familiar with cloud functions?if so then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416769/cloud-function-not-executing

Comment: is there any other solution which does not include cloud functions?

Comment: This is the simplest one. You can create your own mechanism but it's much complicated.