# How to get specific pushedID in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make app like Instagram with Firebase as a backend, while user adds the comment in any photo, new id is generated by Firebase now I want to add one child(likes) when user click on the like button in this randomly generated comment id but the issue is how to get that particular comment id?

[image: pic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can achieve this. So if you want to access a specific comment, you must know something that unique identifies that pcommentll. The first solution would be to store that random id in a variable in the exact moment when you are pushing a new comment to the database using the `push()` method. To get that id, you can use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String commentId = rootRef
    .child(UserId)
    .child(PhotoId)
    .child("comments")
    .push()
    .getKey();
```

You can also save that id inside the comment object if you need to use it later. So this is how it looks like in code:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("noOfLikes", 0);
map.put("commentId", commentId);
rootRef
    .child(UserId)
    .child(PhotoId)
    .child("comments")
    .child(commentId)
    .updateChildren(map);
```

Once you have this `key`, you can use it in your reference to update the number of likes. This type of operation is usually done using [Firebase transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) and for that I recommend see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307610/how-to-save-users-score-in-firebase-and-retrieve-it-in-real-time-in-android-stud)** in which I have explained how to update a score property but same principle aplly in the case of likes.

The second approach would be to create an entire new top level collection like this:

```
Firebase-rot
   |
   --- comments
         |
         --- commentId
                |
                --- noOfLikes: 1
```

Using this solution it will be more easy for you to query the database becuase to get the number of likes you'll need only this simple reference:

```
DatabaseReference noOfLikesRef = rootRef
    .child("comments")
    .child(commentId)
    .child("noOfLikes");
noOfLikesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Fetch the commentID before storing it like this:

   String CommentId = myRef.push().getKey();
2. Save the ID along with comment data:

   myRef.child(CommentId).set(yourValuesHashMap);
3. Now, when you retrieve the comments, you'll have the ID of each comment and you can use that the insert the likes.