# Retrieve Node ID from FireBase Database on CardView Click

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-cardview

I have a firebase database I am using with Android.

To Retrieve and show data from Firebase, I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and results are displayed to CardView.

Now I am getting all listings from my required table to CardView. Every Node has an automatically generated value as shown in the image below.

[image]

How do I retrieve this value in Android when I click on respective CardView. I'll need this value for further database operations.

Now, I tried some of the methods posted here as well as online forums but nothing seems to work. I am not asking for complete code, just how to do it? Some reference code would be great.

Regards

Comment: I found this article here which seems promising but what is PostKey in that answer ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139193/retrieving-data-from-particular-nodes-firebase-database

Comment: have you already show these details in cardview or not?

Comment: I am retrieving data under that Auto-Generated ID.

Comment: ok.. so did you load all node data to cardviews?

Comment: Nope. Just First blue strikethrough line from an image. I want to use ID above that. One that showed by arrow. Starting with Lez........Zp

Comment: @Mahadev have you tried the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the node id try the following:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("Projects");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             String key = ds.getKey();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

First, add a reference to node `Projects` then loop inside of it and retrieve the id using `getKey()`.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. That worked. Now I only have to modify a query for sorting results. That I'll do.