# how to delete one entry in a user in firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to delete one entry in a user in the Firebase database?

[image]

I don’t remember how to delete these entries! help me, please!

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#delete_data If you're having a hard time making that work, edit your question to show where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove that value, you should add to your reference the keys of all nodes. So please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Markers").child(uid);
uidRef.child("-M5957WblHTL3Eu-1jnE").removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Child deleted!");
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: tell me! is it possible to get the line: .child ("- M5957WblHTL3Eu-1jnE") and the rest, get programmatically?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787784/how-to-get-specific-pushedid-in-firebase/51788244)** out.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure of changes of id to given id and Another by using uid.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Markers").(id).child(uid).removeValue();
```

Comment: and what is  .(id) ?? where to get it ??