# How can I get static Firebase value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get a value from Firebase DB. I have a score and I want to check previous value on DB and I will compare these values and set value higher one to DB. Here is my code as follows but I cant take value:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Datas");
myRefchild=myRef.child(uuidstring).child("TimerMode").child("BestScore");

myRefchild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //PrevBestValue=Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            try {
                PrevBestValue=Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("DBhata",e.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });

if (PrevBestValue<TotalScore){
    myRefchild.setValue(Integer.toString(TotalScore));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply get use the value of `PrevBestValue` outside the `onDataChange()` method. Basically, you're trying to use a value synchronously in an API that's asynchronous. That's not a good idea. You should handle the APIs asynchronously as intended.

Firebase APIs are `asynchronous`, meaning that `onDataChange()` method returns immediately after it's invoked, and the callback from the `Task` object it returns, will be called some time later. There are no guarantees about how long it will take. It may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available. Because that method returns immediately, the value of your `PrevBestValue` variable you're trying to use it outside the callback, will not have been populated yet.

A quick solve for this problem would be to move the following lines of code:

```
if (PrevBestValue<TotalScore){
    myRefchild.setValue(Integer.toString(TotalScore));
}
```

Inside the `onDataChange()` method, right after the following line of code:

```
PrevBestValue=Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
```

If you want to use it outside, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

However, I showed you the above solutions to have an understanding regarding asynchronous APIs but this is not the way you should update a `score` field in a multiuser environment. To have consistent data, I recommend you see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307610/how-to-save-users-score-in-firebase-and-retrieve-it-in-real-time-in-android-stud)**, where I have explained how to update a score field using [Firebase Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

Comment: Hi Mahmut! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?