# how to update a column in firebase on successful event?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a firebase database as follows:

```
xyz:

--x:

----m1:

------col1(string)

------col2(string)

------col3(int)
```

I have an android project with **Razorpay** API integrated and I want to increment the value of col3 when the payment is successful.

Here is the **payment.class** file:

```html
package com.example.xxx.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.razorpay.Checkout;
import com.razorpay.PaymentResultListener;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Payment extends AppCompatActivity implements PaymentResultListener {

    EditText value;
    Button pay;
    int payamount;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference db;
    int donation_amt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);

        value = findViewById(R.id.input);
        pay = findViewById(R.id.razorpay);

        pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //define method for payment process
                startPayment();
            }
        });
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("x");
        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<x> m = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot ds1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    x md = dataSnapshot.getValue(x.class);//getter and setter functions are stored in x.class
                    donation_amt = md.getContribution();//getter function getContribution() i.e col3
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });

    }

    private void startPayment() {
        payamount = Integer.parseInt(value.getText().toString()); //storing edittext value and converting into integer type
        Checkout checkout = new Checkout();
        final Activity activity = this;
        try {
            JSONObject options = new JSONObject();
            options.put("currency", "INR");
            options.put("amount", payamount*100);
            checkout.open(activity, options);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPaymentSuccess(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(Payment.this, "Your payment is successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        donation_amt = donation_amt + payamount;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentError(int i, String s) {
        Toast.makeText(Payment.this,"Your payment is unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

On successful payment it doesn’t update the value in the database

Please help.

Comment: You can also check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48308755/5246885)** out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you haven't referenced Firebase back with the `int` variable. You are just incrementing it locally. Something like this should work

```
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference().child("x");
 @Override
    public void onPaymentSuccess(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(Payment.this, "Your payment is successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        donation_amt = donation_amt + payamount;
        ref.child("m1").child("col3").setValue(donation_amt);

 }
```