# Firebase log the times a method was triggered in console

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android app and I have the firebase lib in it.
I was wondering if there a way I can somehow "log" or count the number of times a method was triggered and see it in the Firebase console?

For example, I have a method X inside my android app, and I want to see in my firebase console, how many time the X method was activated (cuz of the user flow in the app)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built-in that can tell you how many times a method is triggered. If you need such a counter, you need to create one yourself. Meaning that every time the method is triggered, update the counter by one. You can achieve that using a transaction, as explained in my answer from the following link:

- [How to save users score in firebase and retrieve it in real-time in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307610/how-to-save-users-score-in-firebase-and-retrieve-it-in-real-time-in-android-stud)

Or by simply using:

```
mDatabase.setValue(ServerValue.increment(1));
```

As explained here:

- [Firebase: update an integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635988/firebase-update-an-integer-value/62636305#62636305)

Comment: Hi Finer! Can I help you with other information?

Comment: can't I use firebase log events for that use case? https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android