# Firebase Realtime Database Transaction

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to run the transaction method but it fails to both get and set proper data in the Firebase Realtime Database.

Following is the code:

```
 private void receiveMoney() {
    String mobile=recipientText.getText().toString().trim();
    Double amount=Double.parseDouble(amountText.getText().toString().trim());
    mDatabase3=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("account_details/Gn2eRixQQiTpvhX870n6nZp66tO2");
    mDatabase3.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(@NonNull MutableData currentData) {

            Double newBalance=(double) currentData.child("initialBalance").getValue();
            System.out.println("Current Balance: "+newBalance+"  Amount: "+amount);

            currentData.setValue(newBalance);
            return Transaction.success(currentData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@Nullable  DatabaseError error, boolean committed, @Nullable DataSnapshot currentData) {

        }
    });
}
```

Following is my database:
[Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1A5Q.png)

Following is the error I get in the Run log:

```
E/RepoOperation: Caught Throwable.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.efikas.SendMoneyActivity$1.doTransaction(SendMoneyActivity.java:86)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.startTransaction(Repo.java:933)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference$4.run(DatabaseReference.java:492)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

enter code here

Comment: May I know what is the error logcat says?

Comment: E/RepoOperation: Caught Throwable.
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference @TicherhazFreePalestine

Comment: The value that you store is not `double`. Can you change the value to 1000.00 ?

Comment: It remains the same,sir. The value pushed into the database is double. @TicherhazFreePalestine

Comment: Can you share the initialize for `mDatabase3` ?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I have only declared the database reference before. And initialized here.

Comment: Have you tested my answer yet?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine, Thank you so much for your help. I did try it. However, it catches another null exception for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increment the value of `initialBalance` with the value of `amount`, there is no need to use any transaction. You can simply increment the value using the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference initialBalanceRef = db
    .child("account_details")
    .child("Gn2eRixQQiTpvhX870n6nZp66tO2")
    .child("initialBalance");
initialBalanceRef.setValue(ServerValue.increment(amount));
```

That's it. If you still want to use a transaction, please check my answer from the following post:

- [How to save users score in firebase and retrieve it in real-time in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307610/how-to-save-users-score-in-firebase-and-retrieve-it-in-real-time-in-android-stud)

Comment: Thank you so much, sir! This works fine. However, could you tell me if it works the same as the transaction method? I am working on a demo e-wallet. So if multiple users push balance at the same time would it still increment data properly?

Comment: Yes, it works exactly like that. You'll always have consistent data. The difference is that you don't have a round trip to the server and back. You get increment it instantly.

Comment: Done, Sir! Thank you so much to you all! Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

I think because you are using `runTransaction` and I think you should focus only 1 thing.

```
mDatabase3=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("account_details/Gn2eRixQQiTpvhX870n6nZp66tO2/initialBalance");
mDatabase3.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(@NonNull MutableData currentData) {
        if (currentData.getValue() == null) {
            currentData.setValue(0);
        } else {
            Double newBalance= (Double) currentData.getValue();
            System.out.println("Current Balance: "+newBalance+"  Amount: "+amount);

            currentData.setValue(newBalance);
        }
        

        return Transaction.success(currentData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@Nullable  DatabaseError error, boolean committed, @Nullable DataSnapshot currentData) {

    }
});
```